# How do you call one side of the off-diagonal entries of a matrix?

Tags: matrices

Given a square $n$-th order matrix, say $A=[a_{ij}]$,

- $a_{ii}$'s are referred to as diagonal entries
- $a_{ij}$'s, $i\neq j$  are referred to as off-diagonal entries

What about in particular $a_{ij}$ with $i<j$? I could think of

- strictly upper triangular entries
- upper diagonal entries

But it seems I couldn't find it used anywhere on the internet. I could be wrong...

Comment: Lower and upper triangulation of a matrix: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition

Comment: @TroyWoo: Do you mean Sub and Super-Diagonal http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Superdiagonal.html?

Comment: @Moo Not only that, also the entries above superdiagonal entries. What do you call that?

Comment: @Moo In light of the LaTeX grammar, we may call them supersuperdiagonal...Just kidding...

Answer (score 1):

People sometimes refer to "the entries above the main diagonal"
 of a matrix.
For example, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41362/how-to-select-all-elements-above-the-main-diagonal-of-matrix

One also sometimes sees a mention of the elements below the main diagonal.

Comment: Thanks...LOL, I can't ... can I just call them nilpotent entries...