# Name for diagonal and upper off-diagonal entries

Tags: matrices

This is in connection with this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2146260/how-do-you-call-one-side-of-the-off-diagonal-entries-of-a-matrix)

Is there a term to call the 'main diagonal entries together with the upper off-main diagonal entries'?

When we say 'upper off-main diagonal', it doesn't include the diagonal entries. I wondering if there is a name for the main diagonal entries together with the upper off-main diagonal entries.

Comment: Triangular matrix?

Comment: By "off-main-diagonal", do you mean anything in the upper triangle, or only the ones immediately above the diagonal?

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about the upper triangle to me.

Comment: @Arthur: By ' upper off main diagonal', I mean all entries above the main diagonal.

Comment: @saulspatz I have edited the question a bit to make it little more clear.